# Android add child views to linear layout without space?

Tags: android

I try to add buttons to the linear layout programmatically .Buttons are added successfully to the linearlayout but between buttons some space is there. I need to remove the space between the buttons how to do this??

I use the following code,but I didn't able to remove the space between the views:

```
   LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Button okButton = new Button(this);
    okButton.setText("some text");
    ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Button okButton1 = new Button(this);
    okButton1.setText("some text");
    ll.addView(okButton1, layoutParams1);

    setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: The spacing between buttons is built-in, you can give your layout backgroun.

Comment: Use layoutParams1.setMargins(-3, -3, -3, -3);  Refer [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361309/remove-space-between-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `layout_margin` parameter as you need like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481455/set-margins-in-a-linearlayout-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Button.setPadding()` when adding the buttons in the layout and set the padding value to zero, if you need to remove padding completely.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
ll.addView(your_button, layoutParams);
```

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; is not a String!!