# Interval between buttons?

Tags: android

I have such layout on my screen[image]

Code is ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:background="@drawable/s21"
android:id="@+id/instructions_view" >

<TextView   
        android:id="@+id/main1name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/main1name"
    android:textColor="@color/orange5" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">

                <include android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                layout="@layout/test_button11"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

               >
            </include>
            <include android:id="@+id/imageView12"
             layout="@layout/test_button12"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

               >
            </include>

            </LinearLayout> 


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">


            <include android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                layout="@layout/test_button13"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

              >
            </include>
            <include android:id="@+id/imageView14"
             layout="@layout/test_button14"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

              >
            </include>
            </LinearLayout> 


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">


            <include android:id="@+id/imageView15"
                layout="@layout/test_button15"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

               >
            </include>
            <include android:id="@+id/imageView16"
             layout="@layout/test_button16"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

               >
            </include>
            </LinearLayout> 


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">


            <include android:id="@+id/imageView17"
                layout="@layout/test_button17"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

              >
            </include>
            <include android:id="@+id/imageView18"
             layout="@layout/test_button18"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"

        >
            </include>
            </LinearLayout> 


            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="horizontal">


            <include android:id="@+id/imageView19"
                layout="@layout/test_button19"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               >
            </include>
            <include android:id="@+id/imageView10"
             layout="@layout/test_button10"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               >
            </include>
            </LinearLayout> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Question is - I don't want to have intervals between buttons onLeft,Right,Top and bottom... How could I do it?

Comment: You make your own `Drawables`(or modify the ones in the SDK) for the `Buttons` as the default ones have some transparent background on them that results in an empty space visually.

Comment: It sounds too difficult, just now I have tryed to use "android:layout_marginBottom="-3dp"..... It works!))

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove space between buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361309/remove-space-between-buttons)

Comment: you are right!) but I've got this way myself)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the same looks like layout via `TableLayout` with 2 columns and 6 rows. Just fill `TableLayout` with buttons. And if you want do delete paddings between buttons you should  put custom drawables into backgrounds of your buttons (default button background have paddings and margins by default).