# Reduce custom button size

Tags: android, android-button

I have created a custom button and placed it in drawable folder, code as below for it:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#f50057" />
    <padding
        android:left="30dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

I am using the above as background for the button, the button is occupying too much space vertically eventhough I have put the padding as 0dp for it. Can you please help me reduce the space occupied by button vertically.

Code in layout:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/expandview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

[image]

Comment: change android:layout_height="wrap_content" with fixed value (exp: android:layout_height="48dp")

Comment: `android:layout_height="10dp"` n try

Comment: plz check this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361309/remove-space-between-buttons . i think helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just specify the desired height and width of the button in your layout XML. i.e

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/start_button"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/expandview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

If you want to do it in drawable.... then

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#f50057" />
    <padding
        android:left="30dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="30dp"
        android:bottom="0dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <size 
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I don't want to change in Button, I want it be global and change it ony in the <shape> tag.

Comment: use   <size /> tag in shape xml...it will make it a global size...mark this answer up and accept it if it helps..

Answer (score 3):

The android button view has a minimum height so if you want something smaller, you have to override it with

```
android:minHeight
```

Like in this code :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Then you can obviously the layout_height parameter but it won't work if your value is below 48 dp (default minimimum height). For instance, the minimum width of the Button view is 64 dp.

Comment: I don't want to change in Button, I want it be global and change it ony in the <shape> tag.

Comment: Why don't you want to change this ? Will it be OK to create a style with your shape in background and the minHeight parameter ?

Comment: That might do if its possible..but is there no way to correct it in shape.

Comment: The thing is that your shape file defines only the background of your button and it's shape (border &  corners). The size of your view cannot be managed from this file.

Answer (score 2):

**you can use the *size* tag to specify the size of drawable and button height ,width will be wrap_content**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#f50057" />
<padding
    android:left="30dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="30dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<size android:height="50dp"
    android:width="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

or you can specify for height and width for specific button like this

just specify the desired height and width of the button in your layout xml. i.e

```
<Button
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:id="@+id/start_button"
android:background="@drawable/myrect"
android:focusable="false"
android:text="Start"
android:layout_below="@+id/expandview"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```