# Remove space between buttons in LinearLayout (Android)

Tags: android, toolbar, margin, android-linearlayout

I need to make my own toolbar in Android application.
Now it looks like this:[image]

So you see spaces between buttons. I tried to put negative margin/padding at buttons, but space didn't disappear.

Here is layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/routes_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </ListView>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_routes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:text="@string/routes"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_places"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/places" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_events"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/events" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_about"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to remove space between buttons?

Comment: Maybe you could check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277732/how-to-get-rid-of-the-extra-gap-between-a-button-and-other-views

Comment: The idea is to use ImageButtons with the same background color...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution. It seems that I hurried to post a question here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/routes_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </ListView>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom= "-7dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_routes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
            android:text="@string/routes"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_places"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/places" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_events"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/events" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_about"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-4.5dp"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Not good answer, with different button style. The values will be different.

Answer (score 24):

Try changing the color of the button, because the default interface of the button which is native to android is actually smaller than it's size, and it's center-fitted to make it look cool.

Change it's background to black or something and you'll see the real size of the button.

android:background="#000"

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer. It doesn't look like there is an actual margin between the button and other buttons, just the background which is applied has some padding on it.

Comment: Wow, really.. I spent quite some time figuring out why I couldn't get rid of space/margin between the Buttons in my Gridview, changing the background like you said showed me, that there really wasn't any space/margin in between them anymore, thanks for this answer.

Comment: Buttons make use of a 9 patch Drawable that makes it look like there is an extra margin around it.

Answer (score 1):

```
I won't suggest to go for -ve margins..
```

Rather setup some background image for button.

**Some Important points:-**

1. The background image itself should not contain any white space at borders.
2. You have to create a selector file for that button after providing background, in which you will describe which image to show in at different states of button likewise `selected`,`focused` etc. other wise you will not be able to see the effects which appear by default (like silver button and when it is clicked it gets orange)

**Solutions :-**

1. How to create a selector you can refer [this lik](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)
2. I have used [this button in my case](http://cdn.dibbus.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/btn_white_matte.9.png)

**My Result :-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/routes_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">
    </ListView>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_routes"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/routes"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_places"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/places" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_events"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:text="@string/events" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_about"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

    </TableRow>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can do it by overriding the default background with has a rounded shape and margin:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            <!--Replace the following color with any other color or drawable-->
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="@string/button1_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score -4):

Add this two lines in all button and use Linear layout instead of tablelayout with horizontal orientation.

```
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:button_weight="1"
```