# How can i delete these spaces in Android

Tags: java, android, button, space

Here is my method, and this method's output is http://l1304.hizliresim.com/18/f/m1r29.jpg

I don't want any spaces between these buttons. How can i do this?

```
public void butonOlustur(){
     TableRow layout1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow1);
     TableRow layout2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
     TableRow layout3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
     TableRow layout4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow4);
     TableRow layout5 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow5);
     TableRow[] layouts = new TableRow[6];
     layouts[0]=layout1;
     layouts[1]=layout2;
     layouts[2]=layout3;
     layouts[3]=layout4;
     layouts[4]=layout5;
     Button[][] myButton = new Button[4][25];
     for(int j = 0; j <myButton.length; j++){
     for(int i =0 ; i <25; i++){

         Button temp = new Button(this);
         myButton[j][i] = temp;
         layouts[j].addView(myButton[j][i], 15, 15);


     }
     layouts[j] = layouts[j+1];
     }


    }
```

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105631/removing-image-button-padding-android/14105941#14105941)

Answer (score 0):

See similar questions answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277732/how-to-get-rid-of-the-extra-gap-between-a-button-and-other-views) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361309/remove-space-between-buttons).

Basically, you can create your own 9patch image, or just change the layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight to negative values.

If you decide to set the margins, you won't want to set it in pixels.  To set the margins to dp rather than pixels, you can use the formula found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255184/android-and-setting-width-and-height-programmatically-in-dp-units).